# extract string between two practices using awk

Tags: bash, awk

i have tried to use `awk` to read string from strings. 
my string:

`str =  /xx/{hello}/xxx/xx{there}/xxx [again]`

i want to extract `hello` and `again`. 
i have managed to to the first thing using :

```
echo $str | awk -F[{}] '{print $2}'
```

but tried to do the same thing for the string between `[]` and i couldn't. also tried `awk -F[[]] '{print $2}'` and `awk -F[/[/]] '{print $2}'`

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think "practices" is a well-understood term for "paired bracket delimiters" or whatever it is that you are hoping for it to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` should help you in same.

```
echo "$str" | awk -F"[]}{[]" '{print $2,$6}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
hello again
```

Also you should assign `str` variable value without space to it as follows.

```
str="/xx/{hello}/xxx/xx{there}/xxx [again]"
```

Comment: @user3439894, not sure I think it was edited before, let me re-phrase my command now and let you know then.

Comment: @user3439894, changed the solution accordingly, let me know if any queries on same please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` program:

```
awk '!(NR%2)' RS='[][{}]' <<< "${str}"
```

What is doing?

Basically we use `{`, `}`, `[` or `]` as the *record separator*. That means awk sees a sequence of the following *records*:

```
/xx/
hello
/xxx/xx
there
/xxx 
again
```

The terms of interest appear always on *even* records. In this case record 2, 4 and 6. `awk '!(NR%2)'` prints records which have an even index.

Comment: Your `awk` command prints `hello`, `there` and `again`, not just `hello` and `again` as stated in the OP, "i want to extract `hello` and `again`".